# Powershell write output to a file

Tags: powershell

I have a script that searches several .eml files for keywords.  What I would like is to output the eml file path and name to a file of all .eml files that match the keyword search.

So I search the .eml file, if it finds the keyword, I output the file path and name to a text file.  I'm not getting the expected output.  Instead, I get the path and name of every file in the directory.  I thought about using a silentlyContinue on the Where-Object, but that didn't work either.

```
$Path = Path to directory with .eml files


$mess = Get-ChildItem $Path\*.eml

$mess |
ForEach-Object {
         Get-Content $_ -raw |
           Where-Object{$_ -match "KeyWord"}
           $_.FullName | out-file output File.txt -Append
            
    }
```

Comment: How about using `Select-String` instead? This way you wouldn't even need a loop. 

Comment: The Select-String doesn't appear to be read the .eml file content.  I need to do the loop because there are about 300 .eml files in the directory

Comment: `Select-String -Path *.eml` loops _implicitly_, and it does read `.eml` files, albeit only _line by line_ (with `-Path` / `LiteralPath` arguments and when piping `Get-ChildItem` output to it), which may be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [lit's helpful `Select-String`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290923/45375):

With file paths as arguments (e.g. `Select-String -Path *.eml ...`) or file-info pipeline input from `Get-ChildItem` (e.g. `Get-ChildItem *.eml | Select-String ...`), `Select-String` invariably searches *line by line*.

Your use of `Get-Content -Raw` suggests that you may want to search *across multiple lines*, which [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) only does if you pass *multiline strings* as input:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -PipelineVariable file $Path\*.eml |
  Get-Content -Raw |
  Select-String 'KeyWord' |
  ForEach-Object { $file.FullName } |
  Out-File File.txt
```

Note:

- The [common `-PipelineVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable) with self-chosen variable `$file` (which must be specified *without* the `$` prefix), so that the input file at hand can be referenced later in the `ForEach-Object` call.
- The solution relies on `Select-String` producing *no output* if the pattern isn't found, so that the `ForEach-Object` call only receives input for matching files.
- The `ForEach-Object` call doesn't actually use `Select-String`'s output object; the fact of receiving input implies that a match was found, and `$file.FullName`, i.e. the full path of the input file at hand is output.
- Note that `-Append` is *not* needed in the `Out-File` call, as this single invocation receives *all* content to write to the file.

---

Alternatively, without `Select-String` (a corrected version of your own approach using the `-match` operator):

```bash
Get-ChildItem $Path\*.eml |
  Where-Object { ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -match 'KeyWord' } |
  ForEach-Object FullName |
  Out-File File.txt
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> $_.FullName | out-file File.txt -Append
> ```

This line in your code isn't connect to the `Get-Content $_ -raw | Where-Object ...` pipeline above it, and therefore executes *unconditionally* for each input file.

To connect it as intended, you'd have to use `|` and *another* `ForEach-Object` call, as follows, but note that the solutions above are simpler and more efficient:

```bash
# Works, but the above solutions are better.
Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw |
  Where-Object { $_ -match "KeyWord" } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.FullName | Out-File File.txt -Append }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Select-String` command will do what you want.

```bash
(Select-String -Pattern 'Keyword' -Path *.eml -List).Path | Out-File -Path File.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Final answer.  Thanks all especially @mklement0

```
$Path = "C:\a\b"
$Match
$NoMatch
ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Path\*.eml -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern $Match -Exclude $NoMatch -List | 
    ForEach-Object path | 
    Out-File G:\APPS\temp\Eric\outfile.txt
      
    }
```